# Printing a number out in AureliaJS with one percision and comma's

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia

I have a number like so that returns from the printOutFunction below:

```
1024248.71345
```

I need it to print out like this:

```
1,024,248.7
```

I am unable to get the comma's working using this:

```
${printOutFunction(variablesToNumber) | number:'1.1-1':'comma' & signal:SendSignalOut}
```

or this:

```
${printOutFunction(variablesToNumber).toLocaleString(undefined, { minimumFractionDigits: 1, maximumFractionDigits: 1 }) & signal:SendSignalOut}
```

But the currency version works like this:

```
${printOutFunction(variablesToNumber) | number:'currency':'USD':true:'1.1-1':'comma' & signal:SendSignalOut}

Output is $1,024,248.7
```

How do I get this to finally be fixed?

Comment: There are almost identical examples in the documentation here https://aurelia.io/docs/binding/value-converters#simple-converters